# ag-grid change row-height of a specific row after button is clicked

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid where 1 of the columns is a button Cellrenderer. And after user click on the button, it shows user a multi-line info. It's cut-off now. And I want that specific row to become higher rowHeight. not changing other rows' height.

I have searched and read other ppl's solution on dynamically fit row to the content of the row, that's not helpful for me because my content doesn't show up unless user click on the button. Thanks.

Comment: can you show an example?